# Why does my onclick funciton only work after the first click?

Tags: javascript, css

I am trying to make one button hide and the button that is already hidden replace where the other button was. My issue is that although my code works the first click does not work and it changes my other functions and throws everything off.

I found the same issue on quora where the answer was to not assume that display starts as "block". After I assigned both 'first' and 'second' displays it has the same issue of only working after the first click.

My html is:

```
        <button onclick="switchSearch();switchType();" id="switch">Switch to zip</button>
        <button id="first">Submit</button>
        <button id="second">Submit2</button>
```

My css is:

```
#first {
    display: block;
    font-size: 48px;
    position: relative;
    left: 20%;
    top: -25px;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: white;
    border: 1px solid black;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 27.5%;
}

#second {
    display: none;
    font-size: 48px;
    position: relative;
    left: 20%;
    top: -25px;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: white;
    border: 1px solid black;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 27.5%;
}
```

My Javascript is:

```
function switchSearch() {
    let a = document.querySelector('#first');
    let b = document.querySelector('#second');
    if (b.style.display === "none") {
        b.style.display = "block";
        a.style.display = "none";
    } else {
        b.style.display = "none";
        a.style.display = "block";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your elements don't have a `style` property, so the first time `b.style.display` is actually undefined. An easy fix would be:

```
if (b.style.display != "block") {
    b.style.display = "block";
    a.style.display = "none";
} else {
    b.style.display = "none";
    a.style.display = "block";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that your `a.style.display` and `b.style.display` return an empty string before you click anything.

Why?

`element.style` doesn't always return actual style property. To check the current `style` value for an element, there's `window.getComputedStyle()` method for you:

```
if (window.getComputedStyle(b).display === "none") {/* ... */}
```

I wouldn't recommend this approach though. It's cleaner to keep your data in variables instead of keeping logic in DOM.

Answer (score 1):

You just have your logic backwards.

Try this:

```
function switchSearch() {
  let a = document.querySelector("#first");
  let b = document.querySelector("#second");
  if (a.style.display === "none") {
    b.style.display = "none";
    a.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    b.style.display = "block";
    a.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

The way you set up the default `display` values made it so the first call to your function just set the displays to what they already were.